# path(' ', views.index, name= 'index'), AttributeError: module 'learning_logs.views' has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, django-3.1

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #Home page,
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
]
```

> Issue is related to views or index please help. `path(' ', views.index, name= 'index')`, AttributeError: module 'learning_logs.views' has no attribute 'index'

Comment: There is a views.py and you want index method inside it, but unfortunately there's no such method.

Comment: please add you `view.py`

Comment: o does this mean that I created and cofigured the urls.py file before the views.py file ,,,and that's why I am getting the errror?

Answer (score 0):

enter code here`In the books python crash course in the later page this error has been resolved by defining a function index. I also had the issue so I read further and it had said to define the index function in views.py.

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this: Here `app_name` is the name of the current application you written `index` function.

```
from django.urls import path
from learning_logs.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    #Home page,
    path('',index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: please add your views.py file for more clarification

Answer (score -1):

Just add an index function in your learning_logs.views.py as:

```
def index(request):
    pass
```